# 1252 collation ignores some unicode characters

Tags: sql-server

The second insert below fails with Primary key violation error

```
create table suni (
id nvarchar(12)  collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS primary key
)

go

insert into suni values(N'Hello');

insert into suni values(nchar(0x202A)+N'Hello'+nchar(0x202C))
```

What collation should I use, to have 1252 ordering and not to drop any unicode character when comparing?

I am testing this in Sql server 2014

Comment: It depends.  What are nchar(0x202A) and nchar(0x202C)?  Are they from a particular language?  This article on [SQL Server collations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250(v=sql.105).aspx) is for SQL 2008, but it should still be applicable for SQL 2014.

Comment: Thanks, when I use a *BIN collate, it works, but i can't find a BIN collate for 1252, only SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN and SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_BIN. Also, the characters are quoting characters (open and close quote) used in bi-directional text

Comment: If I try any of the collations on my system (`SELECT name FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()`), `nchar(0x202A)` and `nchar(0x202C)` evaluate to an "empty string".  BTW, are these the right characters?  `SELECT CHAR(145), CHAR(146)`

Comment: They appear empty, but they are not actually. The select len(nchar(0x202A)+N'1'+nchar(0x202C)) returns 3. Yes finally, I did replace them with "normal" quotes, even if they are not actually equivalent (the 0x202A-0x202C identify untranslated text, that is always left to rigth, even when the surrounding text is right to left), but the question remains